# Mac OS X Nginx - Host multiple local website for development

Tags: macos, nginx, host

I would like to host multiple website in local for development.
For that I have configured hosts file as below, but I can't have access to these websites. When I add the abcd_rev0.dvp in the browser address bar, my browser is loading a google page research instead.
As in the websites log directory, I have no data, it seems that there is no link between the address and the website.
Could you help me.
Thanks in advance

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.0.1      localhost nginx.conf
127.0.0.1       localhost abcd_rev0.dvp
127.0.0.1       localhost abcd_rev1.dvp
#127.0.0.1       dk_analytics_rev0.dvp
#127.0.0.1       dk_analytics_rev1.dvp
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

And the nains.conf file as follow :

```
user  UserId staff;
worker_processes  1;
pid /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;
include etc/nginx/modules-enables/*.conf;

error_log               /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log;
# error_log             /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log  notice;
# error_log             /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name#in_redirect off;

    include             /usr/local/etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Buffer Settings
    ##

    client_body_buffer_size 10k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;

    client_header_buffer_size 1k;

    client_body_timeout 10s;
    client_header_timeout 10s;

    send_timeout 1s;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; #TLSv2 TLSv3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: PODDLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log;
    error_log   /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain;
    gzip_types text/css;
    gzip_types application/json;
    gzip_types text/xml;
    gzip_types application/xml;
    gzip_types application/xml+rss;
    gzip_types text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.congf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


    # Load all configuration files in sites-enabled
    include sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

and the 2 website nains configuration file available in sites-enable and sites-available.
Website 1 Conf File :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  abcd_rev0.dvp; 
    root         /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev0;
    index        index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log   /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev0/logs/access.log;
    error_log    /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev0/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4567/;
    }

    location /images {
        autoindex on;
    }


    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index            index.php;
        include                  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass             127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_buffers          16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size      32k;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root    /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev0/;
            index   error.html;
        }
}
```

Website 2 Conf File :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  abcd_rev0.dvp; 
    root         /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev1;
    index        index.php index.html index.htm;
    access_log   /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev1/logs/access.log;
    error_log    /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev1/logs/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4568/;
    }

    location /images {
        autoindex on;
    }


    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_index            index.php;
        include                  fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass             127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_buffers          16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size      32k;
    }


    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root    /Users/UserId/Sites/Rev1/;
            index   error.html;
        }
}
```

[image: The result of my browser when I try to connect abcd_rev0.dvp website]

Comment: It looks like you are running two different webservers on 2 different ports, http://localhost:4567/ and http://localhost:4568/

Comment: I also have tried without the block location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4568/;
    } But it also doesn't work

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what happens?

Comment: The screenshot has been added